# ToLocalTime() does not work for IST in Blazor client-side razor pages

Tags: blazor-webassembly

An example:
`<input value=@"DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()"></input>`

The value was still UTC for Time Zone IST (UTC+5:30) when I switched to this time zone on my local machine.

Tried a few other Time zones, such as EST (UTC-5:00), Hawaii(UTC-10:00), Beijing(UTC+8:00), all showed local time.

Comment: How did you _switch_ ?  Blazor Wasm should take it from the Browser I think.

Comment: Totally agree, that's what I thought. I switched my time zone on the local host where my service was running and I also used the browser on the same host. The issue was first found when the client-side blazor was deployed in US server and accessed in IST, the local time zone should be the time zone of the client browser, but it showed UTC.